# I can't any get data using mapState in Vue using Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm bit confused with mapState...just check this out

**index.vue**
...

```
    computed: {

        //this doesn't work
        ...mapState(['user']), 

        // this works 
        user () { 
            return this.$store.state.data.user
        }
    }
```

**modules/data.js**

```
...

   const state = {
        msg: 'Tom'
    }
...
```

I assuming `...mapState(['user'])` returns  `user () { return this.$store.state.user}` without `data` object
like LinusBorg explains in this thread https://forum.vuejs.org/t/dont-understand-how-to-use-mapstate-from-the-docs/14454/9

you can check the full code here --> https://codesandbox.io/s/n5z02km81l

Comment: instead of `...mapState(['user'])` it should be `...mapState(['data'])`, and then in your compoment template you would do `<h1>{{ data.user }}</h1>. However there may even be a better way than that to access the data. Im just going based off your current structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your store is divided into modules, you need to use object syntax with `mapState` to access state from a submodule:

```
...mapState({
  msg: state => state.data.msg
})
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/nn0zo023mm

Or you can make the `data` store namespaced, i.e. add `namespaced: true,` to `data.js` module, then access it with:

```
...mapState('data', {
  msg: state => state.msg
})
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/olp064qm55

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for... I end it up using `...mapState('data', ['user']`...but also  something that I notice is that using `namespaced: true` it doesn't load data from a external json file...do you have any idea ?.. I created a new sandbox..https://codesandbox.io/s/1qvxmlkxwl if you want to take a look... I might make a new question if I dont find a soluction

Comment: Your actions also need to be name spaced. Try dispatch `"data/" + DATA`.

Comment: I didn't on my action `export const DATA = 'data/LOAD_DATA` but it didnd't work... it works in the dispatch like you said...but why ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because `user` is a property of `data`

You need to create getters in your store and us `mapGetters` in your component.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

```
export default store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: { ... }
  getters: {
    user => (state) => state.data.user
  }
}
```

Component

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['user'])
  }
}
```